# What are the names of all function from the Lua 5.3 string library?

Tags: string, lua, lua-5.3

Here is a function name register closure which I use to register library names:

The Pool object:

```
function FooBarPool()
  local Names = {}
  local self = {}
    function self:Register(fFoo,sName)
      if(fFoo) then
        Names[fFoo] = sName
      end
    end
    function self:GetName(fFoo)
      return Names[fFoo] or "N/A"
    end
  return self
end
```

Create a Pool object

```
local Pool = FooBarPool()
```

Register known library functions

```
Pool:Register(string.sub,"string.sub")
Pool:Register(string.gsub,"string.gsub")
Pool:Register(string.match,"string.match")
Pool:Register(string.gmatch,"string.gmatch")
Pool:Register(string.find,"string.find")
Pool:Register(string.gfind,"string.gfind")
Pool:Register(string.format,"string.format")
Pool:Register(string.byte,"string.byte")
Pool:Register(string.char,"string.char")
Pool:Register(string.len,"string.len")
Pool:Register(string.lower,"string.lower")
Pool:Register(string.upper,"string.upper")
Pool:Register(string.rep,"string.rep")
Pool:Register(string.reverse,"string.reverse")

for k,v in pairs(string) do
  print(tostring(v) .. " : "..Pool:GetName(v))
end
```

Comment: Please edit your question and to put all info here and delete that "false" answer. Also you can go to http://stackoverflow.com/help and learn how to use this site, welcome to SO by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `print(k,v)` to your last loop, you'll see that you're missing `string.dump`.

The function `string.gfind` is not standard. It was present in Lua 5.0 but was renamed to `string.gmatch` in Lua 5.1.

You can get all the names in the `string` library with

```
for k in pairs(string) do
    print(k)
end
```

or see the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4).

Comment: Yes i know ... duhh just wanted to try out if that's the so called "phantom" function

Comment: Finally the answer I was looking for 
I am Asking IS that was TOO HARD than everyone have to hate everybody here ...

God speed m8

Comment: @Деян Добромиров it's not rage. This is a Q&A site, not a forum and the community try to keep it sanitized and on tracks to keep it clean and organized. You and your questions are welcome, just try to follow de rules

Comment: Yeah, sure I just don't get this. Why they have to vote down for my code .
It's just a code and output  ....  Not that I care or anything.
So you do your super-duper amazing code which does all kinds of stuff and the people star hating it for not particular reason. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Why not list the string library string functions in an array and then iterate
them using the pairs function, thus:
   strings = {"string.sub", "string.gsub", ..., "string.reverse"};
   for _k,v in pairs(strings) do print(v) end;
I find this is easier than the answers given above.
BTW is there a better method to unpack all the string library string functions without resorting to listing them in a table?